# Add Unity 300 to zabbix

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api

I would like to ask about adding Unity 300 to Zabbix. I have done some research on this issue and I have found out that Unity doesn't support installing zabbix agent and snmp. Only snmp trap is allowed. I have added Unity to zabbix and I am able to ping it. I have activated snmp trap and it is working. I was also able to get some metrics with uemcli commands with ssh connection. But is not enough. I have found some templates for Unity 600 but it needs zabbix agent. aklyuk/zabbix-emc-unity. I need more metrics and in another format. Is there another way to get metrics?

Comment: Unity3d is a game engine, if this isn't the thing you are asking for, please remove the tag.

Comment: Unity I think you are referring to is a storage array. This question has no place on a programming forum

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Unity REST API to retrieve metrics. Look for the specs on the EMC KB.